# Export to DAE with textures?

Tags: texturing, export, collada

I'm having trouble in converting OBJ to DAE while retaining textures or at least the colours of the model. Note, this is a voxel model so I only need colours, not detailed textures.

Anyway, I model within MagicaVoxel, then export to .obj, from there I import to Blender. In the scene editor, the model is white. That's ok, if I do a render I see the colours fine. But I need the format in .dae.

Within Blender, I export to .dae but I lose the colours that were packaged with the .obj file.
How do I keep the textures with the .dae file?

I have also tried MeshLab with no results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are exporting to DAE make sure that you export the Material textures, because the texture coordinates are exported correctly but the material doesn't get bound to the texture correctly (and there's no color in the obj, MagicaVoxel uses a palette texture and so it encodes the color in the x component of the UV coordinates).

[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JESub-RWzdYmicfQB6IMWnuy6P4Iksli/view?usp=sharing here it is my project and i cannot see the textures when exported as collada

Comment: This doesn't work for me neither.

Comment: Useless for Blender v3.6+ does not have this option there at all...

Comment: Useless for Blender v3.6+ does not have this option there at all...

Answer (score 1):

Use Blender 2.79 and DO NOT use NODES..
Instead use the "usual image parameter editing methods"..
Export as *.obj and restart.
Blender DAE Exporter supports 5 images..
These are based on

1. Diffuse (Color)
2. Normal
3. Ambient (treated by assimp as the lightmap (a second lightmap UV))
4. Emit
5. Specular (Color)

(there might be more from other apps)