# Export .dae with "include UV Textures & Include Material Textures

Tags: texturing, uv, export

I have a simple blender file and would like to export with textures, however I do not see the option within Blender Version 2.79.

I've come across this questions many times ([ex](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12340/export-to-dae-with-textures)), but my interface is different and I cannot seem to find a solution.

Here is what others have posted they see:

[image]

And this is what I see:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This was changed [as of 2.79](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/More_Features#Collada) and now assumes choosing certain property from the dropdown (UV Textures or Material).

Comment: so what are you trying to archive? Textures are not bundled in your file. Does it not save the textures to the folder where you export your dae file?

Comment: As of 2.82.7 that only has 2 options under "texture options": 1."only selected UV maps" and "Copy", even though the manual says that it should have more, https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export/collada.html. Did anyone solved this? I get all exported models in white.

Answer (score 2):

I have exported many .DAEs with textures from 2.79 without any problems.

The top image you posted is from an older version of Blender. To paraphrase what Mr Zak said, the export menu in 2.79 has changed to what you show in the bottom image.

The settings that work for me are:

[image]