# Why is blender failing to export object textures?

Tags: uv, export, collada

I am very new to blender, and I am trying to export a mesh object with materials/textures as a DAE/Collada file.  When I try to re-import my object into Blender or open it with meshlab, there are no colors/textures/materials included and the entire object is grey.  There seem to be some related questions ([example 1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96421/export-dae-with-include-uv-textures-include-material-textures), [example 2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12340/export-to-dae-with-textures)), but those approaches don't seem to help.

I am using blender 2.79a.  Since the Collada export GUI options seem to have changed recently, I've included a screenshot of the settings I've tried.

Here is a link to the blender file that I am trying to export:
https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/simple-rochet-schneider-1909-fbx-free/1101519

Thanks for your help!

[image: Collada Export Settings]

Update 1: A poster suggested that this is a copy of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures).  I don't believe this is the case, since the linked questionseems to be referring to full, complex, material definitions. Whereas in my use case, I'm trying to export a simple shading material.

Update 2: A poster commented that they didn't have access to the turbosquid link above.  To accommodate I've include a link to the blender file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DNeYYSNaGzGhzb7gzv_8NRT-B-lsuiTt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: You using cycles?

Comment: Duarte - The question you mention seems to be referring to full, complex, material definitions.  Whereas in my use case, I'm trying to export a simple shading material.  With that in mind, I don't think my question is a duplicate.

Comment: David - I'm not sure if I'm using cycles or not.  How can I check for that?