# Blender model to .dae/.sdf with textures

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv, export

I'm working on a project where I need to export a Blender model to a Gazebo model. I am able to do that, but the textures are not showing in Gazebo. I'm using Blender 2.82 and Gazebo9. To my knowledge Gazebo can read .stl and .dae files.

Comment: Hello :). The *.stl* file format doesn't support textures, but you can use Collada *.dae* for that. This thread could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12340/78972

Comment: I don't have that option, the only texture options I have are: 'Only Selected UV Map' and 'Copy'

Answer (score 0):

by textures if you are meaning the materials they don't render in exported objects(read why: [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures))
otherwise textures as images shoud should show up.